# Vue (2.6.11) - object prop missing fields

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel-Vue application that has the function of displaying "projects" stored in a MySQL db. These are complicated objects which are retrieved with the following query via Eloquent:

```
return $this->load([
    'projectVersions' => function($query) {
        $query->with([
            'values' => function($valueQuery) {
                $valueQuery->with([
                    'grid' => function($gridQuery) {
                        $gridQuery->with(['gridCols', 'gridRows.gridCells' => function($cellQuery) {
                            $cellQuery->with(['gridCol', 'gridRow', 'grid' => function($subGridQuery) {
                                $subGridQuery->with(['reference', 'lastGridRow', 'lastGridCol']);
                            }]);
                        }]);
                    }
                ]);
            }
        ]);
    }
]);
```

Although it looks horrible, it returns a straightforward data hierarchy that goes:

```
$project
    -> $projectVersion
        -> $values
            -> $grids
                -> $gridCols, $gridRows
                    -> $gridCells...
```

A "grid" is just a table with cols, rows, and cells that are attached to those rows. In addition however, the cells are also loaded with some information via a with-clause: their column, their row, and their grid, to the latter of which we also attach some more information. These fields are important for handling a cell in various functions on the front-end without having to retrieve its associated grid/row/col etc.

The query works fine, in any case, and we end up with the following array (showing the gridCells of one value):
[image: how the result looks on the back-end]

which is also received on the front-end like so (retrieved through Chrome dev tools):

[image: response retrieved through the Network tab in Chrome dev tools]

However, once that object is loaded as a prop into Vue, we lose some of the information!

[image: retrieved from the Vue inspect tools]

As you can see, we've lost the grid and grid_col fields, even though they were present in the response. I suspect it has something to do with the size of the object - if I cut down the query, the fields show up again - but I need them and there doesn't seem to be any indication anywhere that this is the exact cause. I also cannot find any other instances of this issue online. So, why might Vue be mangling my objects, and is there a way to overcome this short of completely rewriting my app? Thanks!

**EDIT**:
As requested, here is the blade template where the prop is loaded into Vue from Laravel, as well as the prop.

```
@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <project-edit-page
            :project='@json($project)'
        />
    </div>
@endsection
```

and in Vue:
[image: props]

Comment: Show the Vue code that receives the value from your backend, and the code that binds it to a component prop. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: I've added the blade template that passes the prop to Vue  I'm afraid I don't have a link to a reconstruction.

Comment: There's likely a problem in `:project='@json($project)'`. What's the value of `@json($project)`? Can you put that in a data prop in `<script>` and bind that data prop instead?